# How to hide this back button?

Tags: ios, iphone

I want to hide this back button drop down every time I swipe rightwards.How is this possible?

I need a code which I can use it in AppDelegate so that i can use it globally rather than changing it for every ViewControllers.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Select your Navigation Controller and Uncheck Shows Navigation Bar as per below Image

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated:false);
```

Comment: I need a code which I can use it in AppDelegate so that i can use it globally rather than changing it for every ViewControllers.

Comment: you can make slide menu as root view controller to remove back button

Answer (score 0):

Well this code works in `Appdelegate` or in any `ViewController`.

In action of swipe rightwards add following line of code:

```
[[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
```

If you want to show it again use following code in appropriate method:

```
[[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
```

Comment: Will it remove the white drop down also?

Comment: it hides top navigation bar, is it required by you?